# Why do standard applications show slightliy different colors

Tags: windows, winapi, colors

I uploaded a simple png file with a overall fill color here: https://ufile.io/kx1mopq2

If i view this file in the windows explorer or in firefox the color displayed is slightly different than the color shown in Windows Paint, Paint 3d or several other applications i tested - including WinApi and Qt applications i developed myself.
In the screenshot below on the left you see firefox and windows explorer preview - we think that this display color is the correct one. On the right you see Pant and paint 3d. I modified the file in paint as i moved a strip from the left views into the right views in order to make the difference visible.

My question is: Where do these differences have their origin? I want my applications to show the same color as FireFox or Windows Explorer. It seems that there is a application setting or the like that influences that?

Any suggestion welcome.

[image]

Comment: The image may include a color profile that some viewers respect and others don't. Or some viewers may apply a default color profile. Color is complicated.

Comment: Indeed your image contains an "Adobe RGB (1998)" color context/space. Photoshop, Windows Photos Viewer do honor this, while many others don't (Paint, Paint.NET, etc.)

Comment: @Simon Mourier: You were totally right. I was not aware of that. Thanks for your comment.